# Problem with duplicate characters when making an array of struct Node

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a Node struct:

```
struct Node {
    int freq;
    char letter;
    string code;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* up;
};
```

And I have an input reader that should store one of every letter as well as its frequency, but when assigning Nodes to my array through a for loop, I get duplicate letters.:

```
for(int i = 0; i<26 ; i++){
      N[i] = new Node;
      N[i]->freq = alphabet[i];
      N[i]->letter = input[i];  //problem line
}
```

the input array is being passed into the function as a string, and alphabet is an array that stores the frequencies in alphabetical order.
I get that I receive duplicate letters because the input string is directly being put into the array without comparison, but I can't find a way to have it check over other nodes in `N[]` to see if the char member in the Node struct had already been put into the array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you would benefit from `std::map<letter,Node*>`? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: What do you want to do if there is a match in an existing node? You can have a nested loop to find such: `for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) if (N[j]->letter == input[i]) { <whatever> }`. Maybe add some details/clarity to your question.

Answer (score 0):

We won't do it all for you, but we can guide you:

```
for(int i = 0; i<26 ; i++)
{
    Node* node = getNodeForLetter(alphabet[i]);
    N[i]->freq++;

    // might be redundant, but no big deal
    // or you could do that in getNodeFor
    N[i]->letter = input[i];  
}
```

You'll need to code `getNodeForLetter`.

With such a setup, you have a function that gives you the node for a given character. You'll need to conditionally allocate in that function. Then you increment the frequency. And make sure the letter is set correctly.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps.  The return value from `getNodeForLetter` is assigned to a local variable `node` that is never used.

Comment: Well, it's up to OP to figure out where to store it. A `map` might be a good idea.  But with the information we have, it seems the next bit OP needs is "some functionality instead of always performing an allocation". This answer suggest "Put that functionality in a function, that's where the logic goes"